# Python Selenium - override geolocation not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to navigate to Google Maps using selenium webdriver while emulating a different location in Python.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

params = {
    "latitude": 42.1408845,
    "longitude": -72.5033907,
    "accuracy": 100
}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get("https://maps.google.com")
```

When Google Maps opens, I get my current location rather than the one set in `params`.

What am I doing wrong? Using Selenium 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are almost there. you just need to click the your location button. using this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #added
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #added
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC #added

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

params = {
    "latitude": 42.1408845,
    "longitude": -72.5033907,
    "accuracy": 100
}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)
driver.get("https://maps.google.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "widget-mylocation"))) #added
element.click(); #added
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess that does fix the problem. However I'd rather have my location set before I even reach the website (to reduce the amount of interactions with the website itself). Is there any way to do this?

Also, I realize this works for Google Maps, but what if the site does not have a "location" button and displays different content depending on location?

Comment: I would consider this a workaround and not an answer

Answer (score 0):

https://ifconfig.co/
defines the actual coordinates, not the ones passed by cdp.